# Metaplex mpl token metadata returns transaction builder, can we get the instruction?

Tags: metaplex, mpl-token-metadata

i'm trying to use metaplex mpl token metadata v3 to burn an nft, and i need the instruction.
When i use burnNft method, it returns a transaction builder instance.

Is there a way to get only the instruction like in old versions ? (i build the transaction myself)

thanks !

**Edit**

I'm using JS (vue)
I would like to be able to do the following :

```
let transaction = new Transaction()
let instruction = await burnNft(umi, accounts)
transaction.add(instruction)
```

But i'm missing something since burnNft doesn't return an instruction, but a transactionBuilder, and i would like to get only the burn instruction

Comment: what do you mean when you say `get only the instruction`?

Comment: Please specify which language, JS/TS or Rust.

Comment: i'm using JS (vue)
i would like to be able to do the following :
let transaction = new Transaction()
let instruction = await burnNft(umi, accounts)
transaction.add(instruction)

Answer (score 0):

On the rust client side you can use Metaplex builders to do this. https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/blob/main/programs/token-metadata/program/tests/burn.rs

On anchor, you can use the `burn_nft` or `burn_edition_nft`

If you are using a pNFT or cNFT these methods won't work as pNFTs require additional accounts and cNFTs use the `bubblegum program`